# Relationship between partial derivatives for two charts on a Riemann surface

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemann-surfaces

Let's say I have a Riemann Surface $X$. I focus on two coordinate charts $(U_1, \phi_1 = x_1 + iy_1)$ and $(U_2, \phi_2 = x_2 + iy_2)$ on it. On the overlap $U_1 \cap U_2$, do I necessarily have

$\dfrac{\partial (x_1 \circ \phi_2^{-1})} {\partial y_2} = 0$?

This is difficult for me to get my head around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, different charts don't have to agree about which direction is "real" and which direction is "imaginary".  For instance, taking $X=\mathbb{C}$, you could have $\phi_1(z)=z$ and $\phi_2(z)=iz$ and then $x_1\circ\phi_2^{-1}(x+iy)=y$.

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds, and with the same example no less! (+1)

Comment: Thank you -- my only concern is that, then, the definition of $df$ for a smooth function $f$ then doesn't seem well-defined: we have $df = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}dx_j + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y_j}dy_j$ for $j = 1, 2$ on $U_1 \cap U_2$? This is why I mindlessly started wondering the above...I'd appreciate knowing what I'm not seeing right!

Comment: Well, let's take my example with $f=\phi_1$.  In the chart given by $\phi_1$, $df$ is $dx_1+idy_1$.  In the chart given by $\phi_2$, $df$ is $-idx_2+dy_2$.  But these are the same, since $x_2=-y_1$ and $y_2=x_1$ so $dx_2=-dy_1$ and $dy_2=dx_1$.